# Upload image from camera into Firestore from Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

So I have an Object, with the image's name, and url(both strings.)
There is an activity where the user can add a name in an edittext, and then can open the camera, take a photo. Now i want after i click "check mark" on my emulator after i took the picture, to upload the taken picture and the text from the edittext.

I managed to successfully be able to open the camera.

`startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

This is how my camera pops up, i dont know if its possible, to upload as soon as the picture is taken, or do i have to store somewhere locally the picture before uploading it to firestore, not Cloud Storage or Realtime Database.

I have searched through forums, tried to achive this, with getting the image's url and stuff but it wasn't successfull.

Any idea how does it work exactly?

Comment: A Firestore document is going to be too small (1 MB max) to store most camera images. Use Storage instead to store the actual image data, then make a record of that in Firestore if you want.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose)  and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jASD3tkk3ng).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is an activity where the user can add a name in an EditText and then can open the camera, and take a photo. Now I want after I click the "checkmark" on my emulator after I took the picture, to upload the taken picture and the text from the EditText.

That can be very easily achieved.

> This is how my camera pops up, I don't know if it is possible, to upload as soon as the picture is taken, or do I have to store somewhere locally the picture before uploading it to Firestore, not Cloud Storage or Realtime Database?

When you take a picture with the camera on an Android device, the picture is added to the disk first. This is because the camera app needs to store the image data somewhere before you can upload it to a Cloud Service.

However, Firestore is not the best option that you have in order to store pictures, unless you choose to store fairly small icons. Otherwise, I recommend against it. It's true that you can store native binary data in Firestore, but as @DougStevenson already mentioned in his comment, you're going to run up against the [1 MiB limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). So there is really no need to Base64-encode your images.

Instead of storing the images in Firestore, store them in [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and only keep the download URLs in Firestore.